# spring ajax json jquery

Tags: spring-mvc

Can anybody suggest a tutorial where in I can integrate Ajax in my Spring MVC application using JSON library for data exchange????? I have to use jquery with ajax in my application

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jtraining.com/blogs/ajax-with-spring-mvc-and-jquery.html and http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=721#start

Comment: I tried with this tutorial... i had downloaded the json2.2.3 jar file... Does it contain the flexjson.JSONSerializer class mentioned in this tutorial?????? Or is it all together different?

Comment: Which one''s prefered here??? Flexjson or spring-json?? is flexjson library anywhere related to flex???

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/ has a good quick start

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
it is really easy ,you can start from restEasy how to implement  basic RestWEbservice,
then you can make ajax call from webpage to this service,then return from this service json  and parse it very easy if you cant find i can help you

inside spring write a controller like this service

```
   @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("getAllAlbums")
    public String getAllAlbums() {
        List<Album> albums = photoService.getAlbums();
        String albumListasJson = jgen.getFilteredJsonString(albums);
        return albumListasJson;
    }
```

this is json library

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

and ajax side

```
function getAlbums(){
    $.ajax({
        type:       "GET",
        url:        "../rest/xxxx/" + userID,
        dataType:       "text",   //"json"
        cache   :       "false",
        //content :       "document.body",
        success:        function(msg) {
            albums = "{\"albums\":" + msg + "}";
            tplAlb = tmpls['viewId-01'];
            if (tplAlb && albums) {
                data = JSON.parse(aaaa);
                if (data.albums.length == 0) {
                    $.post("../rest/cccccc/" + userID + "/" + "aaaaaaa");
                    getAlbums();
                }
//                alert(data.albums.length);

            }
        }
    });
}
```